# Multiplication of chi-square distribution by constant

Tags: probability, distributions, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Is it true that multiplication of a chi-square random variable by a real constant remains chi-square? I tried to check this using a change of variables, but it didn't look promising.

Comment: It has the same **form** as chisquared, and is usually called scaled chisquare.

Comment: @half-pass A scaled chi-square is not chi-square if the scaling factor is anything but 1. It is still gamma though.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication by a constant changes the scale parameter of a gamma distribution. Since a chi-squared distribution is a special case of a gamma distribution with scale equal to $2$, it is easy to see that if you multiply the random variable with a constant it no longer follows the chi-squared distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suspect this is self-study, here are some hints:

- The characteristic function of a $\chi^2$ is $\phi(t)=(1-2it)^{-k/2}$
- The characteristic function of a $\Gamma(k,\theta)$ is $\phi(t)=(1-\theta it)^{-k}$

(where I worked with wikipedia's notations).

What can you say about $\phi_{cX}$ and $\phi_X$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that multiplication of a chi-square random variable by a real constant remains chi-square.

Chi-square is sum of square of independent **standard normal distribution**. Multiplying a non-one constant will make the summation not by **standard** normal anymore.

Comment: Yes, therefore it should be called "*scaled* chi-square", as kjetil b halvorsen commented :-)